# Why "catch" doesn't handle rejected promise?

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, promise

I have a very simple function that gets a number and returns a Promise. I don't understand why if the promise was rejected I can't catch it when I call this function? Instead node throws **"Exception has occurred"**.

```
function check(num) {
  return new Promise((resolve , reject) => {
    if (num > 2) resolve('good')
    else reject('bad') 
  })
}

check(1)
 .then(res => console.log(res))
 .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: It should work fine if you just run it with `node`. Your IDE might be doing something weird. (Also, you’ll generally want to reject with `Error` instances to keep everything working smoothly, like `new Error('bad')`.)

Comment: I edited your post but was rejected... If you use a snippet to run it, you'll see it works fine in the browser.

Comment: Your code works fine. Just tried it in chrome console as well as node app.

Comment: sjahan, @Ryan thank for help! The problem really was in VS Code...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code should run without any issues. The problem is in the IDE/debugger.

If you're using something like Microsoft Visual Studio Code and running with breakpoints, you should be able to set what kinds of exceptions IDE should throw.

Usually you can find several options in the debugging panel stating when to signal for exceptions, like `All`, `Uncaught`, `Promise rejects`, etc. So try to check the debug panel in your editor.

[image]

Comment: thank you Kid! It works with unchecked "Uncaught Exceptions"!